# Where to find the externally accessible IP address when accessing an RDS instance in a VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I have made an RDS instance inside a VPC publicly accessible:

[image]

Will there be a publicly accessible IP address now?  Where would I find it in the `aws console` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you would use URL of the DB instance to connect to it. But if you want the IP, you can check it in **EC2 console -> Network Interfaces**:

[image]

Comment: By `ec2 console` do you mean `ec2 dashboard`? If so there are 0 ec2 instances - so then where is this `network itnerface`?

Comment: @javadba Hi. On the screenshot, you see a menu on the left with "network interfaces" at the bottom.

Comment: OK see it now. The IP Address shown is the resolved IP address of the `Endpoint` so those do line up thx.   I still can not connect to the RDS instance: times out. There are other thing(s) I'm still missing apparently. Really hard to get connectivity to an RDS on a publicly accessible vpc: could not find any complete instructions.

Comment: @javadba What about security group of your RDS? Have you modified them to allowed incoming connection from your IPs or internet?

Comment: I am having trouble following the security group to the vpc: the vpc itself does not have an associated security group?  I don't see it on the gui.  OK I think found it under the same `Network interface` tab.  It was set to completely open : i changed to my laptop ip address. But that's *more* restrictive so we still have the original question,

Comment: @javadba Can you update the question with the screenshot of your SG settings. You can also make new question if you want.

Comment: oh that's interesting: setting my laptop IP address actually allows it to work!

Comment: @javadba Glad to hear that :-). It must had been incorrectly set then.